# Assembler MASM и FASM меняют JC на JB?

Tags: ассемблер

Пишу под Дос на Ассемблере COM программку.
После вызова 21 прерывания, если флаг С установлен, нужно перейти на вывод ошибки. Ошибок нет и программа в файл ничего не вывела.
Запустил Дебаггер и вижу что после INT 21h, вместо JC (переход если переполнение) везде стоят JB !
Запустил FASM, скомпилил, Дебаггером смотрю везде JB стоят!

Что за глюк? (Дебаггер от Борланд если что)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Откройте любую документацию по опкодам для x86 процессоров ( например, эту, первую, которую нашел в поиске https://faydoc.tripod.com/cpu/jc.htm ( и Вы увидите, что у JB и JC один и тот же опкод 72 хх. И это не удивительно - они проверяют один и тот же флаг. Что именно отображать - решили разработчики отладчика, но с точки зрения процессора - это **одна и та же инструкция**.

Comment: И что делать? :) Как уточнить им что я хочу JC а не JB? Или это Дебаггер так показывает?

Comment: Я могу конечно JNC применить, но это как то странно :)

Comment: Смотрю как другие обрабатывают ошибки после INT 21h. Там JNC :)

Comment: Заменил на JNC и как вы думаете что произошло? JNB !!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @FrancNet, с точки зрения процессора JC это то же самое что JB, JNC то же что JNB (эти команды проверяют одни и те же биты в регистре флагов). Разница только "семантическая" (типа, что имел в виду программист), и только в ассемблерном виде (до компиляции), опкод после компиляции у каждой из этих пар команд получается одинаковый. Вообще нет никакой возможности сделать так, чтобы эти команды компилировались в разные опкоды, да и нет никакого смысла в этом.

Comment: @FrancNet P.S. итог: нет никакой проблемы в том, что отладчик показывает JB "вместо" JC (или наоборот), это одна и та же команда. Ничего исправлять не нужно.

Comment: я думаю, что когда компилятор (ассемблер) сгенерирует правильную отладочную информацию, то там будет правильная мнемоника, но это нужно экспериментировать.

Comment: @KoVadim, вообще да, если в отладочной информации есть номера строк, то отладчик по идее сможет смаппить машинный код на исходник, и показать как было в исходнике, со всеми комментариями, неразвернутыми макросами и т.д. Но обычно для показа исходника открывается отдельное окно (насколько я помню, в OllyDbg так было, в турбо дебаггере вроде бы тоже), в дизассемблерном окне как было так и останется (JB "вместо" JC).

Comment: в каком то отладчике я видел возможность выбрать, какую именно мнемонику показывать, но это было лет 15 назад и сейчас уже не помню имя. может это ida.

Comment: Хорошо. Тогда вопрос! В INT 21h при работе с файлами, если возникает ошибка, код ошибки в AX и устанавливается C флаг. Как тогда по завершении обработать правильно ошибку? Я на Ассемблер 8086 перешел с z80 (ZX Spectrum). Множество логики построено на С флаге. Как мне тогда поменять логику? :)

Comment: Если Ваша программа составлена на языке ассемблера, то после обращения к DOS через прерывание следует проверить состояние флага переноса:

int     21h
jc      error

Из документации по DOS 3+ :)

Comment: @FrancNet если вы хотите проверять флаг C, то пишите JC. Не вижу никаких проблем.